# Common mistake for unexpected token in json at position 0 json codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, json, codeigniter

I am developing a login module in my project using jquery/json using Codeigniter. I have 4 data in my users table; namely a,b,c,d and these users is admin for designated states(state 1,state 2,state 3,state 4).

When user a logged in, it will redirect to localhost/xxxxx/administrator/state1/dashboard and so on.

My code is running earlier but right now i am encountering this error unexpected token in json at position 0, how can I solve this problem?

**VIEW**

```
 <div id="dialog" class="dialog dialog-effect-in">
    <div class="dialog-front">
      <div class="dialog-content">
        <form id="login-form" class="dialog-form" method="POST">
          <fieldset>
            <legend>Log in</legend>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="user_username" class="control-label">Username:</label>
              <input type="text" id="email" class="form-control" name="email" autofocus/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="user_password" class="control-label">Password:</label>
              <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" name="password"/>
            </div>

            <div class="pad-top-20 pad-btm-20">
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-block btn-lg" value="Continue">
            </div>
          </fieldset>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**JS**

```
function login_error_message(idname,message) {
        $(idname).html('<div class="alert alert-danger text-center" role="alert">'  + message +  
          '</div>');
      }
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#login-form").on('submit',function(e){
      $.ajax({
      url: base_url + 'administrator/login',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data)
        {
          var result = JSON.parse(data);
          if(result === "state1")
          {
            $("#validate_error").html("");
            window.location.href=base_url+"administrator/state1/dashboard";
          }
          else{
            login_error_message(".alert-login",result)
          }
        },
        error: function(data)
        {
          alert('Opps! Something went wrong. please contact the administrator. ');
        },
      })
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  });
```

**Controller**

```
public function login() {

        if($this->form_validation->run('login_validate') == FALSE) {

            echo json_encode(validation_errors());
        } else {
            $email = clean_data($this->input->post('email'));
            $password = clean_data($this->input->post('password'));
            $where = array('email'=>$email);
            $get_user = $this->Crud_model->fetch_tag_row('*','users',$where);

            if($get_user) {
                $check_password = $get_user->password;
                $get_state = $get_user->state;
                if(password_verify($password,$check_password)) {

                    if($get_user->status == 'Active') {
                        if($get_state=="state1"){
                            $user_session = [
                            'id'        => $get_user->id,
                            'email'     => $get_user->email,
                            'first_name' => $get_user->first_name,
                            'middle_name' => $get_user->middle_name,
                            'last_name'  => $get_user->last_name,
                            'state' => $get_user->state
                        ];

                        $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in',$user_session);
                        $session = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');                  
                        $this->session->id          = $session['id'];
                        $this->session->email       = $session['email'];
                        $this->session->fullname    = $session['first_name'] .' '. $session['middle_name'] .' '. $session['first_name'];
                        $this->session-state   = $session['state'];
                        echo json_encode("state1");
                        }

                    }elseif($get_user->status == 'Inactive'){
                        echo json_encode("Your account is inactive. Contact our human resource department regarding this problem.");
                    }

                }else {

                    echo json_encode("Invalid Credentials");
                }

            }else{
                echo json_encode("Invalid Credentials");
            } 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specific the key if you want to use JSON as response, example:

**Controller**

```
$r = [
  'status' => 'invalid'
];

echo json_encode($r);
```

**JS**

```
success: function(data)
        {
          var result = JSON.parse(data);
          if(result.status === "invalid")
          {
            $("#validate_error").html("");
            window.location.href=base_url+"administrator/state1/dashboard";
          }
          else{
            login_error_message(".alert-login",result)
          }
        },
```

Comment: Isnt the same with mine? my json_encode is indicated to state1. It worked earlier but now i dont know what happened :/

Comment: That is totally different, have you compare my code and your code then tried it?

Comment: Hi sir, Is it possible to have 2 specific key? For example, may first echo json_encode("success"); and the other one is echo json_encode("state");